# How to pass ssl_verify_mode option to chef-client.exe

Tags: chef-infra

I want to pass explicitly ssl_verify_mode option to chef-client (executable). On this page https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html I am not able to find any option for this. Although there is --config-option but whenever I use

```
chef-client --config-option ssl_verify_mode=verify_none
```

chef-client completely ignores the settings. Is there any way I can run this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding that value in chef-client default configuration file (client.rb) or create new configuration file and pass it with `--config`.

```rb
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none
```

I found that https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4918 however is for old chef-client version.

Comment: Hi, that's the issue, I don't want to use file with --config. Want to use --config-option directly with chef-client command. Is there any way around

Comment: as far I check that- no :(

Comment: you should edit your client.rb or create other configuration file.